# Seeing TransferSpreadsheet Run time Error 3125 when exporting Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export data from Excel to my Access db but am seeing the following error:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
Sub ExportReport()

    'declaring our files, directories, tables and field names
    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    Dim MasterDB As Worksheet
    
    sheet = "Overall Activity" & "!"
    
    strPath = "Z:\High Exposure Administration Team\HET - Management Reporting\"
    
    strTable = "ActivityTable"
    
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "Weekly Activity Reporting Tool.xlsm")
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, sheet
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

'Overall Activity' shouldn't be too long for a table name. Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: Probably doesn't like the "!" in the range argument.

Comment: Use $ instead of ! to import entire worksheet without referencing range.

Comment: If Overall Activity is actually a defined table in Excel, I don't think can use in TransferSpreadsheet.